# Numpy stick arrays horizontally

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays A and B with the same number of rows. I want a new array C, which is A appended on the right hand side by B. I can't find the function to do that. How can I do it?

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html#numpy.hstack

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
>>> b = np.array([[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])
>>> np.hstack( (a, b) )
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 4,  5,  6, 10, 11, 12]])
```